# Neo4j indexing doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, lucene, batch-insert

I'm using batch insertion method for creation of neo4j graph db. Loading DBpedia data set and constructing the property graph of it.

```
public Neo4jBatchHandler(BatchInserter db2, int indexCache, int timeout) {
    this.db = db2;
    this.indexCache = indexCache;
    this.timeout = timeout;

    BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(
            db);
    index = indexProvider.nodeIndex("ttlIndex",
            MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
    index.setCacheCapacity("__URI__", indexCache + 1);

}
```

this the code which I am using for indexing.

---

During Query operations I want to use Indexing possibility for efficiency. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is the my code:

```
    IndexHits<Long> hits = index.get("__URI__",
                    resourceName);
```

it returns null, but I'm sure that db contains the resource with the `resourceName`. How should I use indexes here, for query?

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually add the nodes to the index? For example:

```
index.add(node,properties)
```

Are you querying during the batch insertion process? If so, flush the index

```
index.flush();
```

so that the newly indexed nodes are visible for querying. It is recommended that you do not do this frequently, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-batchinsert.html

Comment: I did both of them. Unfortunately, result is same.